What are all the steps needed to migrate from Video Embed WYSIWYG to Core Media (images/video fields too)?
As the title suggests, I'm in the process of upgrading from Drupal 9 to 10 and would like to finally migrate over to Core Media, as opposed to just using inline video/images/files as we have for the last many years.
I have followed How to Migrate from Video Embed WYSIWYG to Drupal Core Media, but feel like I am missing something as it didn't seem to do anything for me.
I copy and pasted the supplied update hook code into a custom module and ran a database update, which told me the hook was applied. However, I don't seem to notice anything changing to my site.
Am I missing something? Is there another step after this in order for me to uninstall video_embed_wysiwyg and use core media for all active content?
Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated (preferably a with depth explanation). I'm not one who has lots of knowledge with hooks/PHP in general, but can use it when needed.

I assume you already checked dblog and there were no errors.  So in that case, I would use xdebug to watch the hook execute. Set a breakpoint on the entity query and make sure that it returns the data you expect (the entities you want to convert).  It looks like the code would throw an exception otherwise, so if you didn't see any errors, it may be that the query is just not returning any data in the first place.
